# Megamenu and powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Is there a way for me to have a SharePoint Online modern list that I can use to make item entries in the SharePoint Megamenu via powershell?

SharePoint list has:

**URL**  - name of my SharePoint page that I would like to appear in the megamenu

**AD groups**  - security groups applied to the page

**Is active** - checkmark to indicate if I want this entry to be shown on the menu or not

**Menu** - the title in the megamenu where I want my entry to appear under

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSOM to add Top Navigation Link in PowerShell, here is an example you can follow: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-add-link-top-navigation-using-powershell.html

And you can use power shell to turn on/off megamenu like this blog:http://www.letsharepoint.com/how-to-enable-megamenu-in-sharepoint-modern-sites-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/

For the idea about use list to control, you may need to run the script every time the list is modified which is not quite a good approach.

Comment: You could use Power Automate (Flow) to trigger your script (stored in an Azure Runbook) when the list is updated. It does seem like a rough way to do it though!

Comment: @Gizmo3k Thanks for the note! I should not forget that way.